# AWS cloudfront - how to serve s3 and EC2 using single cloudfront?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to serve S3 and EC2 using single cloudfront?

Steps I followed so far are -

1. Deployed a react app on S3 bucket
2. Deployed a nodejs app on EC2

Both apps are running with their separate public DNS. I am trying to serve both apps using single cloudfront for example -

http://dyiqp9sog17kw.cloudfront.net  >> it should serve react app, it is working as expected.

and

http://dyiqp9sog17kw.cloudfront.net/api >> Here I want to run my node app from EC2 but it is throwing **Access Denied** exception.

I am not sure if it is possible or not. Please help!!

Comment: You can create a separate folder in your s3 bucket, say `node_app`. And in the folder's settings set it as static web hosting and redirect requests to your actual node app address.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I need to run JAVA API on EC2 so can't use S3 stand alone

Comment: You will be using s3 to just forward the requests from the single CDN to your node_app. Once you receive the request on your EC2 (maybe sitting behind nginx) you should be pretty much able to whatever you want.

Comment: See this is what I am willing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446347/path-based-routing-to-cloudfront-and-ec2 
but now in my case cloudfront url for EC2 is now redirecting, check it please - http://dyiqp9sog17kw.cloudfront.net/api